# How to create mutually dependent components using Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have two mutually dependent classes that I want Autofac to instantiate. Basically, the parent needs a reference to the child, and the child needs a reference to a service that in this case the parent happens to implement.

```
public class Parent : ISomeService
{
    private IChild m_child;

    public Parent(IChild child)
    {
        m_child = child; // problem: need to pass "this" to child constructor
    }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public Child(ISomeService someService)
    {
        // ...store and/or use the service...
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should really avoid circular dependency. In your case, one solution would be to split the `Parent` class in two distinct class

Comment: @CyrilDurand, can you elaborate on specific issues you've run into with circular dependencies? It's very common for object graphs to have cycles in them, so it's often hard to avoid.

Comment: It's more design issue than concrete technical issue. It often indicates a design issue that indicate your components is not [solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). The workaround to introduce the circular dependency will also make the code less readable and test mockup will be more difficult. [Circular dependency on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) also discuss about some problems with circular dependencies.If possible try to avoid theses dependencies by introducing a new component, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a rather elegant solution using [parameterized instantiation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b). It allows the child's dependency on `ISomeService` to be resolved using an existing object (the `Parent` instance) without introducing any messy lifetime issues (as far as I can tell):

```
public class Parent : ISomeService
{
    private IChild m_child;

    public Parent(Func<ISomeService, IChild> childFactory)
    {
        m_child = childFactory(this);
    }
}

public class Child : IChild
{
    public Child(ISomeService someService)
    {
        // ...store and/or use the service...
    }
}

// Registration looks like this:

builder.RegisterType<Parent>(); // registered as self, NOT as ISomeService
builder.RegisterType<Child>().AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

Works like a charm. :)

Comment: This is fantastic - sir... you are a steely eyed missle man!